# paypal API v2 how to reload after transaction completed

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

This question is about paypal v2 API on how to relaod the page once transaction completed.

With my actual code I can perform the transaction and it is saved successfuly in my database.

the only part is how to reload after full execution ?

here my code

```
paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.create({
                purchase_units: [{
                  amount: {
                    value:\''.$amount.'\',
                  }
                }]
              });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
              return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                
                return fetch("/__path_to_save_db.php", {
                  method: "post",
                  headers: {
                    "content-type": "application/json"
                  },
                  body: JSON.stringify({
                    orderID: data.orderID,
                    paymentID: data.paymentID,
                    payerID: data.payerID,
                  })
                });
              });
            }
          }).render("#paypal-button-container");
```

I tried to add a javascript reload but it reloads before the end of execution :(

here

```
 return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    location.reload();
                    return fetch("/__path_to_save_db.php", {
```

it seems that location.reload() is triggered too quickly.... how to make it execute only once the paypal answer is fully loaded ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not be capturing payments on the client side and then depending on the client to send this information to a server.

Change this to a proper client server payment integration. Create two routes, one for 'Set Up Transaction' and one for 'Capture Transaction', [documented here.](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/)

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Your code to display a success message -- or do a page "reload" or redirect, if you are feeling like an old-fashioned web 2.0 designer -- should go in the case that is handled when the server returns a successful capture.

Comment: But with this code : in the PHP side I do echo 'something' and it is not shown anywhere in the html of the page :( how can I add a taget div to return the "echo" of the PHP ?

Comment: The server-side code above does not output to a web page, so speaking of a target div makes no sense.  It is for an asynchronous request, and will output JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works for me

```
 return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    if(confirm("transaction completed")){ setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 1000);}
                    return fetch("/__path_to_save_db.php", {
```

the "confirm" after a 1 second delay to have a dialog that when clicked, it reloads